# How to design custom EditText in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am developing apps in android. I did design custom edittext for my apps see image.1 for image.1 i used edittext style but I want edittext style like following image.2. does anybody have solution.

image.1 
[image]

image.1 edittext style

```
 android:background="@drawable/edittext_shape"
```

following is the edittext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:left="-4dp"
    android:right="-4dp"
    android:top="-4dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="@color/marooncolor" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Following is image.2 whcih is I want

[image]

Comment: do you have image like the image2 ??? that red color strip ?

Comment: no i don't have image.

Comment: if you have a image means that is an easy one to do .

Answer (score 0):

create a 9 patch drawable that will only stretch horizontally and set it as the background of your EditText..

Comment: you mean to say, create custom image write.

Comment: all i meant was you want that maroon underline in your EditText. It actually is a 9 patch image drawable. So you'll have to create that image first.
you can create 9 patch image using [this](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html) site

Answer (score 0):

The other way of doing this is use Relative Layout having Edit text and ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use [android holo colors](http://android-holo-colors.com/). Generate `styles` and `9patch` files for your custom `EditText`, copy and apply to your project. It should work especially if you need the `EditText` like in Androids Holo Theme.

Comment: I think android holo colors style not working on version less than 3.0 correct.

Comment: So you think wrong. On the other hand, you should make your own style on the basis of holo generated styles and apply (copy) to your project only `9patches` files. But it requires your effort.